# How do I mock Outlook.MailItem with multiple Attachments using NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, outlook, nsubstitute

I'm trying to unit test a static function that accepts an [Outlook.MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia) argument type:

`public static bool GetMailAndDoSomething(Outlook.MailItem mailitem)`

Here is what I have so far in my test function:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
...
public void TestGetMailAndDoSomething()
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Substitute.For<Outlook.MailItem>();

    Outlook.Attachments attachments = Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachments>();
    attachments.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
    attachments.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
    attachments.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
    attachments.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());

    mailItem.Attachments.GetEnumerator().Returns(attachments.GetEnumerator());

    Assert.True(Misc.GetMailAndDoSomething(mailItem));
}
```

Inside the GetMailAndDoSomething function, there is a piece of code that I want to test

```
foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in mailItem.Attachments)
{
       //do someting
}
```

However, the test program never reaches `//do something` because mailItem.Attachments always seem empty. This is what I see when my IDE breaks at the `foreach` line.

[image]

What do I need to fix in the test function so that the test program will reach `//do something` in the targeted function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform implementations on an interface.

[`Attachments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments?view=outlook-pia) is derive from `IEnumerable`

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("0006303C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Attachments : System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

Consider using an actual list as a memory store and then setting up the mock to return that

```
var list = new List<Outlook.Attachment>();
list.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
list.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
list.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());
list.Add(Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachment>());

Outlook.Attachments attachments = Substitute.For<Outlook.Attachments>();
attachments.GetEnumerator().Returns(list.GetEnumerator());

Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Substitute.For<Outlook.MailItem>();
mailItem.Attachments.Returns(attachments);

//...
```